# How to get a JSON property value using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

I have a table named appsettings with columns value and key

key column = supported-api-client

in value column i have json like this

```
{
    "DEV": [
        { 
            "OS": "android", 
            "Version": "28",
        },
        { 
            "OS": "ios", 
            "Version": "1.0.0.1", 
        }
    ] 
}
```

how do i take these two from that  "OS": "android", "Version": "28". any posibilities?

Comment: Are you really using two different unsupported Postgres versions? 9.1 didn't even support JSON at all.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce it in postgres 9.4: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/4278

```
SELECT value -> 'DEV' ->> 0
FROM appsettings
WHERE key = 'supported-api-key';

//output
{ "OS": "android", "Version": "28" }
```